# Emulating TO_SECONDS() in older versions of MySQL (<5.5.0)

Tags: sql, mysql, time

For performance and simplicity reasons I would like to get the contents of a DATETIME column in my MySQL 3.x server as seconds (or any numeric type really - I just want to avoid all the apparent nastiness of timezones when using UNIX_TIMESTAMP() [the dates in my table are indeed from different locales so I'd rather not have any doubt as to whether or not some timezone-compensation weirdness is going on behind my back]).

The TO_SECONDS() function seemed ideal, until I found out that it only works on newer MySQL installations (upgrading is not an option)...

I though about doing something like this:

```
SELECT (TO_DAYS(Timestamp)-730486)*86400+TIME_TO_SEC(Timestamp)
```

To manually calculate the number of seconds elapsed since 2000-01-01. But it seems like it might put unnecessary load on the server by forcing it to make a temporary table or something?

I could also just do:

```
SELECT TO_DAYS(Timestamp), TIME_TO_SEC(Timestamp)
```

and combine the results myself, but that makes it less simple on the code-side.

What's the best compromise? I'll be fetching a large number of rows (on the order of 10^6) each query, so both client and server-side performance is not entirely unimportant..

Thanks,.

(post edited to reduce confusion)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, just to make sure, the new field will be a `BIGINT`... correct?

Can you use explicit casting in to prevent the overflow?

```
SELECT CAST(TO_DAYS(Timestamp)*86400 + TIME_TO_SEC(Timestamp) AS UNSIGNED INTEGER)
```

Or perhaps use an intermediate string before populating the new `BIGINT` field?

```
SELECT CAST(TO_DAYS(Timestamp)*86400 + TIME_TO_SEC(Timestamp) AS UNSIGNED CHAR(11))
```

Comment: New field? No, the data is being extracted to a client program for further processing and display to the user (it's a C/win32 program using ODBC - I've got that part well in hand). Re. your suggestion, I realized that I can just subtract an offset from the 'days' portion to get the values to fit in a suitable range: SELECT (TO_DAYS(Timestamp)-730486)*86400+TIME_TO_SEC(Timestamp). So this isn't a problem anymore. Now it's just the question of, is this actually a good idea? Isn't it 'bad' in some way to ask the server to do a bunch of arithmetic on temporary results?