# TO_SECONDS working on windows not on linux

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE TO_SECONDS(NOW())-TO_SECONDS(TS) <= 604800
```

TS is timestamp column.
604800 is the time in seconds 7 days.

This query runs perfectly on locally on windows but when I upload it to the Linux server it stops working.

Comment: Are you sure main problem is query ? Can you test it on mysql command panel?

Comment: can you clarify what does not work?

Comment: It may be happen that when you are receiving it , just see what variable you are using. It might be out of variable's scope.

Comment: `stops working` is not an explanation. Do you have mysql installed?

Comment: Yes it works fine on cmd panel.

Comment: just found this error   FUNCTION database.TO_SECONDS does not exist

Comment: Throw an `or die(mysql_error())` at the end there, and debugging on the rest of the connection-related lines of code, to backtrack through possible errors.

Comment: Compare PHP versions on both linux as well as windows server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TO_SECONDS only exists in SQL version >= 5.5, check what version you have on linux. Most likly the version with your distro is out of date.

A solution without upgrading is here:
[Emulating TO_SECONDS() in older versions of MySQL (<5.5.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617812/emulating-to-seconds-in-older-versions-of-mysql-5-5-0)

Comment: But TO_SECONDS AND TIME_TO_SEC are totally different. But as the old query was running on windows and not on linux saying function doesn't exit. So I too think it was the problem with version.

I got it, I have just changed the query a bit.
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tlb_users WHERE TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(NOW(),TS)) <= 604800 ");

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is case sensitive (sometimes?) when it runs on Linux, and never when run on Windows.  Perhaps TS is of a different case?

I may be completely wrong, this may only affect table names, but I have experience this issue  before.